# Is there a way to select a "dynamic" column based on LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
   cid,
   COALESCE(newcust.newcust, false) AS newcust,
   COALESCE(svipstat.svipstat, false) AS svipstat,
   COALESCE(vipstat.vipstat, false) AS vipstat
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cid, true AS newcust
    FROM customer c
    WHERE active IS TRUE AND created_at >= current_date - interval '1 day' * 30
) AS newcust ON newcust.cid = c.cid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cid, true AS svipstat
    FROM customer c
    WHERE active IS TRUE AND (select count(1) from visits where cid = customer.cid and vdate >= current_date - interval '30 days') >= (SELECT value FROM criteria WHERE c = 'svipstat' AND criteria.pid = c.pid)
) AS svipstat ON svipstat.cid = c.cid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cid, true AS vipstat
    FROM customer c
    WHERE active IS TRUE AND (select count(1) from visits where cid = customer.cid and vdate >= current_date - interval '30 days') >= (SELECT value FROM criteria WHERE c = 'vipstat' AND criteria.pid = c.pid)
) AS vipstat ON vip.cid = c.cid;
```

What this query returns, is something like this:

```
cid | newcust |  svip | vipstat
--------------------------------
1.     true.     false.    false
2.    false.    true.      false
3.    false.    false.     true
```

My ideal scenario, would be if I can have a column return a "string", based on the LEFT JOINS I have, for example:

```
cid | status
-------------
1.    newcust
2.    svip
3     vipstat
```

Is there a way to achieve this??? I've been having a hard time trying to find a solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `CASE WHEN` logic to choose the `status` value in the outer query like this

```
SELECT
    cid,
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(newcust.newcust, false) 
         THEN 'newcust'
         WHEN COALESCE(svipstat.svipstat, false) 
         THEN 'svipstat'
         WHEN COALESCE(vipstat.vipstat, false)
         THEN 'vipstat'
    END status
FROM ...
```